# 3 Graph API Endpoints - inserting column from one to another after matching

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

At the moment, I am querying 2 different Graph API endpoints, getting M365 active user details as well as user detail from the users endpoint, and matching the userPrincipalName to the employeeNumber. employeeNumber is a value that is currently an extension attribute.

I am trying to query a 3rd Graph API endpoint to get Office activation details:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActivationsUserDetail`

The logic currently looks like this:

```
#queries
$graphApiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D90')"
$activationsUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActivationsUserDetail"

$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$select=userPrincipalName,extension_335d2348b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber"

Write-Output "Querying Graph API for Office activations..."

$ActivationReport = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $activationsUri -Headers $headerParams | ConvertFrom-Csv

# If the result is more than 999, we need to read the @odata.nextLink to show more than one side of users
$UserDetails = while (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($uri)) {
    # API Call
    $apiCall = try {
        Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headerParams -Uri $uri -Method Get
    }
    catch {
        $errorMessage = $_.ErrorDetails.Message | ConvertFrom-Json
    }
    $uri = $null
    if ($apiCall) {
        # Check if any data is left
        $uri = $apiCall.'@odata.nextLink'
        $apiCall
    }
}

$O365Report = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $graphApiUri -Headers $headerParams | ConvertFrom-Csv
Write-Output "Matching UPN to employeeNumber..."

$O365Report | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentEmpNumber = $UserDetails.value |
        Where-Object userPrincipalName -eq $_.'User Principal Name' |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty extension_335d2348b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name extension_335d2348b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -Value $CurrentEmpNumber
}

$O365Report | Export-Csv $ReportCSV -NoTypeInformation
Write-Output "Report saved to $ReportCSV."
```

I am trying to simply grab the column called `"Last Activation Date"` from the getOffice365ActivationsUserDetail report, match it using `User Principal Name`, and insert into the final CSV output as a separate column. I am unsure how to proceed, as I already have those members added as part of the previous foreach loop. Both reports contain a column with the header `"User Principal Name"`

The call to the Graph API endpoint is as follows:

`$ActivationReport = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $activationsUri -Headers $headerParams | ConvertFrom-Csv`

Not sure if it is as simple as:

```
$LAD = $activationReport | Select-Object 'Last Activated Date'

$O365Report | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentEmpNumber = $UserDetails.value |
        Where-Object userPrincipalName -eq $_.'User Principal Name' |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty extension_335d2348b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name extension_335d2348b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -Value $CurrentEmpNumber
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Last Activated Date' -Value $LAD
}
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you have mentioned at the bottom may not work. The reason being there is no connection between the $activationReport and $o365 repport

You could  use the below snippet to achieve your goal.

```
 $O365Report | select 'User Principal Name', @{N="EmpNum";E={$tmp=$_.'User Principal Name';($UserDetails|?{$_.'User Principal Name' -eq $tmp}).extension_335d2348b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber}}, @{N="LastActivatedDate";E={$tmp=$_.'User Principal Name';($ActivationReport|?{$_.'User Principal Name' -eq $tmp}).'Last Activated Date'}}
```

**Explanation :**

It creates column `LastActDate` by evaluating the expression

```
E={$tmp=$_.'User Principal Name';
($ActivationReport|?{$_.'User Principal Name' -eq $tmp}).'Last Activated Date'}}
```

**Expression Evaluation :**

It stores the `$tmp` with the value of User Principal Name of the `$O365Report`

Then goes to the `$ActivationReport` filters the user Principal name equal to the `$tmp`

Filtered object.'Last Activated Date'* is stored in the column of the `LastActDate`

Comment: Thank you! I think this is a great starting point. Is it possible to simply just insert the LastActDate column into the already existing output? Your expression seems to output UserPrincipalName and LastActDate onto the console. I'd like to retain the Microsoft report, and simply just insert LastActDate. It also appears EmpNum is null.

Comment: You will do a Expand Property empnum. Or Like you mentioned *simply just insert the LastActDate column into the already existing output*. If you want it to be stored in a file. Pipeit (|) witha `Export-CSV` command

Comment: How would I add LastActivationDate column to the following code? ```$O365Report | ForEach-Object {
#    $CurrentEmpNumber = $UserDetails.value |
#        Where-Object userPrincipalName -eq $_.'User Principal Name' |
#            Select-Object -ExpandProperty extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -Value $CurrentEmpNumber
#}```

Comment: $currentEmpNumber will have the desired output right ?

Comment: `$currentEmpNumber | select 'User Principal Name',@{N="LastActivatedDate";E={$tmp=$_.'User Principal Name';($ActivationReport|?{$_.'User Principal Name' -eq $tmp}).'Last Activated Date'}} ,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber`

Comment: I think so - the output already currently works and uses the reports endpoint, and it is currently inserting the employee number. I just want to insert the activated date as an additional column - just like I am doing with add-member and the $CurrentEmpNumber.

Comment: Are you saying it needs to look like this: ```$O365Report | ForEach-Object {
    $currentEmpNumber | select 'User Principal Name',@{N="LastActivatedDate";E={$tmp=$_.'User Principal Name';($ActivationReport|?{$_.'User Principal Name' -eq $tmp}).'Last Activated Date'}},extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber
}```

Comment: Sorry my bad, you could store the modified output of the $o365report. Then add the employee number to it. 
`
`$office365report| select 'User Principal Name',@{N="LastActivatedDate";E={$tmp=$_.'User Principal Name';($ActivationReport|?{$_.'User Principal Name' -eq $tmp}).'Last Activated Date'}} ,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber
`

Comment: I got the variable name worng

Comment: Understood - but this only outputs 3 columns. Userprincipalname, LastActivatedDate, and the employeenumber (which is still null) The code currently queries the Microsoft ```getOffice365ActiveUserDetail``` endpoint, and then matches and inserts the employeenumber into that report. I am just looking to insert LastActivatedDate from the other endpoint into the existing report output. I will see what else I can do with your code - thanks!